# unset the manager changes activity feed in SharePoint 2010

Tags: user-profile

We wanted to unset the manager changes activity feed for all the users are in the SharePoint 2010 farm, have used the below code

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Server;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.ActivityFeed;

namespace MysiteActivityOFF
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
           {
               string currentSite = "http://weburl";
               using (SPSite aSite = new SPSite(currentSite))
               {
                   SPServiceContext currentContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(aSite);
                   UserProfileManager userProfMan = new UserProfileManager(currentContext);
                   ActivityType activityType = null;
                   string userName = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;
                   UserProfile currentUser = userProfMan.GetUserProfile(userName);
                   ActivityManager activityMan = new ActivityManager(currentUser, currentContext);
                   bool rights = activityMan.PrepareToAllowSchemaChanges();<br/>
                   if (rights)
                   {
                       try
                       {
                           activityType = activityMan.ActivityTypes["ManagerChange"];
                           activityType.IsPublished = false;
                           activityType.Commit();
                           activityType.Refresh(true);
                           Console.WriteLine("Manager change activity successfully disabled for user : " + currentUser.DisplayName);
                       }
                       catch (Exception ex)
                       {
                           Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                       }
                   }
                   Console.ReadKey(true);
               }
           });
        }
    }
}
```

however it throws the below error:

> ERROR : 
>   =======
>  In the "activityType.Commit();" line the exception occurs at :
>
> Message :
>  ActivityManager.ActivityFeedSchemaMapping
>   Exception
>    Inner Exception :
>  Procedure or function
>   activityFeed_UpdateActivityTypes has too many arguments specified.
>   StackTrace :
>     at
>   
> Microsoft.Office.Server.ActivityFeed.ActivityFeedSchemaMapping.InsertOrUpdateOne(ActivityFeedSchemaMapping[]
>   mapping, Object obj, String sproc, SqlSession sqlSession, Boolean
>   isInsert)
>     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.ActivityFeed.ActivityType.Commit()

```
Powershell:<br/>
$loginname = "domain\account";<br/>
$site = get-spsite https://url<br/>
$context = Get-SPServiceContext $site;<br/>
$upm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context);<br/>
$profile = $upm.GetUserProfile([string]$loginname);<br/>
$am = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.ActivityFeed.ActivityManager($profile, $context);<br/>
$am.PrepareToAllowSchemaChanges();<br/>
$mgrChange = $am.ActivityTypes["ManagerChange"];<br/>
$mgrChange.IsPublished = $false<br/>
$mgrChange.Commit()<br/>
```

> Error:
>
> Exception calling "Commit" with "0" argument(s):
>   "ActivityManager.ActivityFeedSchemaMapping Exception" At line:1
>   char:18
>   + $mgrChange.Commit <<<< ()
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

**Update-2:**

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System") 
$loginname = "domain\user"
$site = Get-SPSite "URL"

$context = Get-SPServiceContext $site;
$upm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context);
$profile = $upm.GetUserProfile([string]$loginname);

$am = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.ActivityFeed.ActivityManager($profile, $context)
$apptList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Office.Server.ActivityFeed.ActivityPreferencePerType]

$am.ActivityTypes | ForEach-Object {
  $appt = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.ActivityFeed.ActivityPreferencePerType
  $appt.ActivityType = $_
  $appt.IsSet = $false
  $apptList.Add($appt)
}
$am.ActivityPreferences.SetActivityPreferencesPerType($apptList)
$am.ActivityPreferences.Commit()
$am.ActivityPreferences.Refresh()
```

Irrespective of the user, it updates the service account profile(on which logged into the server). what could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

The class is ActivityPreference. ActivityManager class accepts userprofile object but it has to match the current user ([see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee585780.aspx)). If not it seems to retrive from httpcontext or windows identity. Also it looks like it cannot be impersonated with system account. To update the propety under user context use something like below.

```
        string siteUrl = "http://site/";
        string managerType = "ManagerChange";


        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
        {
            SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
            UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
            UserProfile profile = profileManager.GetUserProfile("domain\\username");

            ActivityManager activityManager = new ActivityManager(profile, serviceContext);
            List<ActivityPreferencePerType> apptc = new List<ActivityPreferencePerType>();

            foreach (ActivityType type in activityManager.ActivityTypes)
            {
                ActivityPreferencePerType appt = new ActivityPreferencePerType();
                appt.ActivityType = type;
                appt.IsSet = false;

                if (type.ActivityTypeName.ToLower() == managerType.ToLower())
                {
                    appt.IsSet = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    appt.IsSet = true;
                }
                apptc.Add(appt);
            }
            ActivityPreferencesCollection coll = activityManager.ActivityPreferences;

            coll.SetActivityPreferencesPerType(apptc);
            coll.Commit();
            coll.Refresh();
```

In PowerShell (using reflection to set preference for another user).

```
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System")

$loginname = "domain\testuser"
$site = Get-SPSite "http://site"

$context = Get-SPServiceContext $site;
$upm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context);
#$myprofile = $upm.GetUserProfile("domain\myusername")
$profile1 = $upm.GetUserProfile([string]$loginname)

$am = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.ActivityFeed.ActivityManager($myprofile1, $context)

$type = $am.GetType()
$methodInfo = $type.GetMethod("CopyBasicUserInfo", [reflection.bindingflags]"nonpublic,instance", $null, $profile1.GetType(), $null)
$methodInfo.Invoke($am, $profile1)

$apptList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Office.Server.ActivityFeed.ActivityPreferencePerType]

$am.ActivityApplications["UserProfileChange_Gatherer"].ActivityTypes | ForEach-Object {
  $appt = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.ActivityFeed.ActivityPreferencePerType

  $appt.ActivityType = $_

  if($_.ActivityTypeName -eq "ManagerChange") {
    $appt.IsSet = $false
  }
  else {
    $appt.IsSet = $true
  }
  $apptList.Add($appt)
}
$am.ActivityPreferences.SetActivityPreferencesPerType($apptList)
$am.ActivityPreferences.Commit()
$am.ActivityPreferences.Refresh()
```

This [blog](http://madalina.blog.com/2011/02/sharepoint-2010-programmatically-change-activities-that-i-follow/) talks about it in more detail.

Comment: Great help..I wounder if we could permanently unset the Manger change activity feed and allow the users to set on demand. any suggestions?

Comment: Irrespective of the user, it updates the service account profile(on which logged into the server). what could be the issue?

Comment: See edited response.

Comment: I had tried the same code as above but it is not impersonating for any user .its still updating the service account only .Can you please help me with this

Comment: You cannot impersonate activitymanager, although you could use reflection to set the target user infomation (see ps script in the ans)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My requirement is that i need to hide some of the default activities that the user follow in activity feed . I designed a console but when i am hard coding the user also it is updating only for service account .Is there a way to achieve this for all users ...

Comment: "ActivityManager manager = new ActivityManager(user, context);
Type type = manager.GetType();
MethodInfo setContextUserMethodInfo = type.GetMethod("CopyBasicUserInfo", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { user.GetType() }, null);setContextUserMethodInfo.Invoke(manager, new object[] { user });" where user is userprofile of target user

Comment: Also do not use answer to post further question. Use comments box.

Comment: I found I had to move $apptList.Add($appt) to immediately below $appt.IsSet = $false (inside that if()) and remove the else, otherwise it sets every activity feed type to false.