# Share Point Activity feed power shell script error

Tags: powershell, activity-feed

```
#Add SharePoint PowerShell SnapIn if not already added
 if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System")

$site = Get-SPSite "http://mysite/"
$context = Get-SPServiceContext $site;
$upm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context);
$profile1 = $upm.GetEnumerator()


while($profile1.MoveNext())
{

        $am = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.ActivityFeed.ActivityManager($myprofile1, $context)

        $type = $am.GetType()
        $methodInfo = $type.GetMethod("CopyBasicUserInfo", [reflection.bindingflags]"nonpublic,instance", $null, $profile1.GetType(), $null)
        $methodInfo.Invoke($am,$profile1.Current)

        $apptList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Office.Server.ActivityFeed.ActivityPreferencePerType]

        $am.ActivityApplications["UserProfileChange_Gatherer"].ActivityTypes | ForEach-Object {
              $appt = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.ActivityFeed.ActivityPreferencePerType
              $appt.ActivityType = $_ 
              $Username = $profile1.Current.DisplayName


              if($_.ActivityTypeName -eq "Birthday_Reminder") {
                $appt.IsSet = $false
                write-host "Updating Activity Feed Property Birthday_Reminder for " $Username              

              }
              else{
               $appt.IsSet = $true
              }
              $apptList.Add($appt)
            } # For Each Object Ending
        $am.ActivityPreferences.SetActivityPreferencesPerType($apptList)
        $am.ActivityPreferences.Commit()
        $am.ActivityPreferences.Refresh()
} # While Userprofile Ending`enter code here`
```

Comment: Anil, could you please format your code and move the comment you left for Per Jackobson up into the comments section of his answer?

Comment: Question originated from here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/31958/2070

Comment: @RobertKaucher Hi Robert i had formatted the code and added the logic to repeat it for all users but now i am getting the following error.Can you please help                                      'You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the foreach on userprofiles with this `while($profile1.MoveNext())` and `$profile1.Current` will return you the current user profile. Sample

```
$upm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
$iterator = $upm.GetEnumerator()
while($iterator.MoveNext())
{
   Write-Host $iterator.Current.DisplayName
}
```

Comment: Can you please see my updated code with the logic you told me . i am getting the following error .You cannnot call a method on null valued expression

Comment: The line $methodInfo = $type.GetMethod(..),  Replace $profile1.GetType() with $profile1.Current.GetType().

Comment: The object is null. I imagine that sssreddy's suggestion will fix that.

Comment: Thank you very much both of you .It fixed the issue ...You really saved me a lot of time ....

Comment: Hi All , If i want the  Update  happen only to group of audience that i had created instead of the complete user profile ,Can you tell me how i can achieve that using power shell

Answer (score 1):

You are piping ActivifyTypes into an foreach which you're also using to loop through $AllProfiles you need two foreach instead of one

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when i am running it through the userprofile enumerator it is giving me the following error. Can you please help me. But it is running in the loop

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
> C:\Users\servicet\Desktop\ActivityFeedComplete.ps1:31 char:19
> + $methodInfo.Invoke <<<< ($am, $profile1.NTName)
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Invoke:String) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull